# Is merchantship faster?

Tags: arche-age

Just a quick question.  Is the merchantship costing 400 Guilda Stars faster than other ships?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Merchant Schooner is faster than the Fish-Find Longliner, Lutesong Junk and Eznan Cutter.:

```
Adventure Clipper      | 11.1m/s
Harpoon Clipper        | 11.1m/s
Merchant Schooner      | 10m/s 
Fish-Find Longliner    | 8.3m/s (11.1) 
Lutesong Junk          | 7.4m/s (8.4)
Eznan Cutter           | 7.4m/s (8.4)
Black Pearl            | 10.8m/s (14.2 max)
Heavy Galleon          | 6.5m/s (??.? max)
Luxury Liner           | ??.?m/s (??.? max)
```

[Source: ArcheAge Wiki](http://archeage.gamepedia.com/Ships)

Comment: This might be inaccurate. I found different values at http://www.ign.com/wikis/archeage/Ships and http://archeage.info/ships